# gorm.Model timezone configuration using sqlite

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm w/ sqlite. My model includes gorm.Model so gorm handles for me created_at, ... but by default it saves all the auditing dates using the local time  (e.g. "2019-08-12 17:45:39.356009+02:00"). Is there a way to force the UTC for the auto generated fields? Is the behaviour based on gorm itself or also on the underlying sql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read a bit into the code, you will see that the `delted_at`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` fields are controlled by the function `gorm.NowFunc` [link](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/utils.go#L20).

According to the docs:

```
//    gorm.NowFunc = func() time.Time {
//      return time.Now().UTC()
//    }
```

Comment: Thanks @sberry! Just to make sure I fully understood the scenario (Sorry but I'm a go newbie). I could place the snippet gorm.NowFunc... into my app main to make sure it will be always applied or also call db.SetNowFuncOverride(myNowFunc) just after I created my gorm.DB always into my main (I create the gorm.DB in main and I'll inject as dependency into all my sub classes)

Comment: @Crixo Yes, exactly!  I hadn't even seen the `SetNowFuncOverride`.